# Can't login because password contains characters not in keyboard

Tags: login, password

Recently I set a password containing small c cedilla (ç) and now I can't type it on login menu because it doesn't use the Spanish but English keyboard and types a slash, resulting in wrong password. How could I login?

Comment: With a bit of luck, it might be available via ALTGR+c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to reset you password. First restart your PC, wait for the GRUB menu to appear(similar to this)[image: grub menu]

Now, select the **Advanced option for Ubuntu** and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>
There will be two options, select the option to go to recovery mode.

Now you will be present with different options of recovery mode. Now you have to  choose **Root Drop into root shell prompt**

You need to have write access to the `root` partition. By default, it has only read-only access using the command

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Now, list all the users that are present in the system

```
ls /home
```

Use the command

```
passwd username
```

where `username` is the  user from the list whose password is to be reset. `passwd` is used to set a password

It will prompts for a new password. Enter the new password twice (there will be no visual feedback i.e: you wont see any characters on the screen)

Then exit the root shell prompt by typing `exit`

When you exit, you will be back to the recovery mode menu. Select `resume` for normal boot option.